# cmake, scribus - List all required libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, build, dependencies, scribus

I'm trying to build Scribus (1.5.8 and 1.7) from source in Ubuntu 20.04. It uses cmake as its build system. I have no experience with cmake.

**Is there a way to get a list of all the required and/or optional libraries from cmake or any command line tool?**

Right now, my "workflow" is the following:

1. Run `cmake .` in source directory.
2. If it fails, go to 3. Else, go to 7.
3. Search error messages for mentions of missing libraries.
4. Run `apt search` to find (hopefully) right library.
5. Run `apt install` to install (hopefully) right library.
6. Goto 1.
7. Proceed.

This is very tedious. My hope is to have something that just generates a list of libraries that cmake will look for. Ideally, this list could simply be given to `apt install` to pull in all the libraries.

Although the scribus developers provide lists of required libraries in their wiki, these lists do not seem to be exhaustive or up to date.

I tried using `cmake --graphviz=foo.dot`, but it only generates any output after I got `cmake .` to run successfully.

Comment: Maybe you can use `apt-get build-dep scribus`?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this tool existed! It seems to do exactly what I asked for, regarding the Scribus version in the Ubuntu repositories. But since I'm trying to compile the latest version from their svn repository (sorry, I didn't write it clear enough in my question), there could still be some dependencies that build-dep won't reflect, right?

Comment: That is correct, which is why I didn't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get a list of all the required and/or optional libraries from cmake or any command line tool?

Not in an automated way. Generally that is not possible. There may be dependencies not managed by CMake, outside of CMake code, there may be dependencies of dependencies, and many corner cases. Also, there is no clear mapping between "library name" and "project name" (I mean, between .so or .a or .h ile and the actual project where it comes from).

Generally, compiling a library *requires* (manual) knowledge about that library and the library dependencies. This is exactly the work that *package maintainers* in distributions do - they compile the libraries and list all library dependencies for package managers. While there come ever smarter "build systems", this is not a silver bullet, and C++ ecosystem is *way* too diverse.

---

But sure - you google `scribus`, find the sources https://github.com/scribusproject/scribus , check the documentation, and find the dependencies of a project https://github.com/scribusproject/scribus/blob/master/BUILDING , all listed:

```
Requirements:
    Qt >= 6.2
    Freetype >= 2.1.7 (2.3.x strongly recommended)
    cairo >= 1.14.x
    harfbuzz = > 0.9.42
    libicu
    libjpeg (depending on how Qt is packaged)
    libpng >= 1.6.0
    libtiff >= 3.6.0
    libxml2 >= 2.6.0
    LittleCMS (liblcms) >= 2.0 (2.1+ recommended)
    poppler and poppler-cpp >= 0.62.0
    hunspell
    Python >= 3.6

Recommended:
    CUPS
    Fontconfig >= 2.0
    GhostScript >= 8.0 (9.0+ or greater preferred)
    tkinter for the font sampler script
    python-imaging for the font sampler preview
    pkgconfig (to assist finding other libraries)
    podofo - 0.7.0+ for enhanced Illustrator AI/EPS import, svn versions
    boost and boost-devel
```

Build systems are still a *huge* way forward - with `cmake .` the library maintainer can display a fancy error message for users `"Och - install libpng, it was not found"`, which makes it all pleasant. It is still way better than getting `-lpng: not found` messages from the compiler or linker. You could for example write a CMake configuration that lists all such messages, and errors later, so that users see them all.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Especially pointing me to the BUILDING file was a great help. Don't know how I could have missed it.

Comment: What I don't understand is, why it is not possible to figure out the dependencies automatically up front. I thought that this information should be "hidden" somewhere in all those cmake files. If it wasn't - how could cmake "know" anything about required libraries at all? I mean, it *does* tell me, when it didn't find a library it was looking for, doesn't it? It just stops after the first miss. What's the point that I'm missing here? Thanks again!

Comment: `why it is not possible to figure out the dependencies automatically up front` Is explained in the first two paragraphs. Is something unclear? `how could cmake "know" anything about required libraries at all?` CMake does not - compiler does. CMake passes `-lpng` compiler flag and compiler "finds" the library. `It just stops after the first miss` As said, it is possible to implement that, it requires additional work, like a flag, etc. The author of this project didn't implement it - I also wouldn't, it's not worth the time.

Comment: From what I understood so far, cmake reads the cmake configuration files and generates makefiles from them. There are cmake commands like "find_package" and "pkg_check_modules" that invoke routines that try to locate the libraries etc. on my system. Those locations are then (maybe) used in the makefile and when compiling. To me, this seemed to contradict the statement, that figuring out the dependencies from cmake files was not possible in general. But I think I see your point now regarding practical limitations of such an approach.